# Is the World Bank organisation halal to work for?

Tags: halal-haram, riba, banking

I currently work for a World Bank funded project in the procurement department. Recently i have been questioning myself whether my income is halal. The way it works is World Bank hhas an agreement with our governmentto provide funds for a certain project. In somecases the project funding is partially a loan while the other part is a grant or credit. The staff such as myself are paid from the allocated project funds. We are responsible for carrying out all the activities of the project with the main part being the procurement or purchasing process. When the project is completed the government pays back the loan portion of the funds to World Bank sometimes with interest. The staff are not involved in prepayment. To my knowledge any interests or additional amounts have not been paid for any project activity contract even if there is 1 clause in the contract. The respevtive clause has never been enforced. Therefire with regard to the interest issue and World Banks own fundraising procedures, i am kind of reflecting on my employment situation. All responses are welcome. Thank you very much in advance.